# Tenses writing a biography

Tags: grammar

Which tense to use asking questions about a person`s career whose career is over but the person is alive? Presnt Perfect or Past Simple?

Comment: Simple past. The present perfect implies that the action still has relevance for their life. Incidentally, you can get a good quick idea by checking a Wikipedia article on a deceased person, e.g. [Leonard Cohen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Cohen).

Answer (score 1):

English has an odd habit of changing things like direction or verb tense depending on *which perspective* you are talking from.  Whether you use simple past or present perfect (or some other tense) depends on the context:

> **Is** Mel Brooks the greatest comedian **of our time**?
>
> **Was** Mel Brooks the greatest comedian **of his generation**?

In some cases either is fine, because the topic is sometimes considered *timeless*.  Movies, for example:

> **Has** Mel Brooks **written** some of the greatest comedy movies ever?
>
> **Did** Mel Brooks **write** some of the greatest comedy movies ever?

An exception is that the *present perfect progressive*, which implies some condition is still ongoing. If the subject has retired, it would not make sense to ask:

> **Has** Mel Brooks **been writing** great comedy for over 60 years?

Instead use the simple past to imply that he no longer writes comedy:

> **Did** Mel Brooks **write** great comedy for over 60 years?

Disclaimer:  Mel Brooks is quite old, but he might not actually be retired.

Comment: Apparently Mel Brooks does voiceover in [recently-released] [*Blazing Samurai*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4428398/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1). Along with another hero of mine - the legendary ***Samuel L.** [Jackson]* - so I guess I'll have to consider watching it. Bet it won't be as good as *Blazing Saddles* though.